# CSS errors? Margins not applying / white space at bottom

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have two questions im sure are very simple I'm just looking over something.

1.) To start off, my website is mostly HTML, except I have a WordPress blog page. To make the blog page look like the HTML home page, I modified the header.php and footer.php, and everything looks fine except one problem.
As you'll notice if you compare the Home page with the Blog page, for some reason the margins I have to position the navigation links & social media icons isn't working but it works on the home page? I really have no idea why it isn't working, the stylesheet is linked correctly and everything, as every other style works fine except the margin in those areas.

2.) At the bottom of the home page there is a white space below the footer, but its not on the WordPress blog page? I am trying to remove the white space but have had no luck. The only way I can remove it is if I make the footer 30px larger, which I don't want to do. I have set heights on the HTML, Body and am unsure why the space is there.

Thanks ahead of time, I appreciate you taking the time to look at my questions.

**EDIT** here is a link to the site:

http://jqwebexamples.com/iAM_Talent/Version3-rev/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<p>` Tags in your footer are the problem. If you remove (or disable it temporarily) the following style:

```
#footer p {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

then the white line disappears. Take a look in firebug to check this out.

The other issue looks like caused by the unsorted list in your navigation div.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue :)